# PMF of two poisson random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

A book publisher employs two typists, X and
Y. Typist X makes typographical errors at the rate of k per page, and Y makes
them at a different rate of r per page.
**a**. Considering that both X and Y do half of the entire publisher's typing,
write down an expression for the PMF of the random variable E, the
number of errors on a randomly chosen page.
**b**. Write down the PMF of E if the typist with the error rate k types 70
percent of the pages.

According to merging principle, my PMF should be distributed over Poisson(k+r) but I'm confused with the "half of the entire publisher's typing" and "70% of pages". I'm unable to incorporate this information. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merging principle is only when you are counting the total number of Poisson distributed events in the same time interval. But each page is a separate interval.

It is even easier: By the law of total probability,
\begin{align}
P(E = e) &= P(E = e \mid \text{$X$ typed the page}) P(\text{$X$ typed the page}) \\
&\qquad\qquad+ P(E = e \mid \text{$Y$ typed the page}) P(\text{$Y$ typed the page}).
\end{align}
The first factor of each term is the Poisson pmf corresponding to the error rate of the typist.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But we are assuming here that each page is typed by only one typist. What if that's not the case?

Comment: You are assuming Poisson typists.  But the problem did not specify the distribution of errors per page attained by each typist.  For all we know, typist Y van be perfect but spiteful, and commit precisely 13 errors on every page she types.

Comment: Got it. And if I have to calculate the expected value of this PMF, would it be sum of corresponding weighted means?

Comment: Yeah (that is the law of total expectation, which is easily derived from what you have).